# Struggling with positioning divs around page

Tags: html, css

I've been working on this for days and feel like I've tried everything. Not sure if it's just something small that I'm missing or if I'm completely off track. I need to position my divs on the page like in this image [image]the code I've got so far is this.

**HTML:**

```css
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 1024px;
      height: 768px;
      float: left;
    }

    .pagebanner {
      height: 200px;
      width: 1024px;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      padding-left: 200px
    }

    .navbar {
      background-color: brown;
      float: left;
      height: 768px;
    }

    .subheading {
      background-color: chartreuse;
      padding-left: 420px;
      margin-top: 0px
    }

    .content {
      background-color: crimson;
      height:
    }

    .footer {
      background-color: darkgreen;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0px
    }
```

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <title>The Club Site</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div wrapper="mainwrapper">
        <div class="pagebanner"><img src="HTML Pract A/images/banner.jpg" alt="PageBanner" width="1024px" height="200px">
          <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="header">
            <h1 class="header">The Club Site</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="subheading">
            <h2>Members Prices</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <p>blah blah blah</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. First time trying to use HTML and I'm not having much luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

In this sample i try to introduction [bootstrap framework](https://getbootstrap.com) to you, bootstrap can help you to make a lot of html templates with less time, try t read documentation of this framework and you will figure out how it's easy.

> Good luck with it and always before you ask something search about it,
>   i'm sure you will get solved questions.

*This sample based on bootstrap 4 framework*

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #ccc;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.sub-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>The Club Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>header</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 nav">
        <h3>nav</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col header">
            <h3>The Club Site</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col sub-header">
            <h6>sub header</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 1</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 2</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 3</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 4</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 5</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
            <div class="item">
              <h4>item 6</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap for the win! :)

Comment: It's for a course I'm doing, Im don't think they want me to be using bootstrap. I've spent days on this watching videos, reading stackoverflow threads. They want me to base the website on a 102 x 768 resolution. Would you be able to tell me if I am close at all with my current code? The main issue is I'm getting gaps under the banner and can't figure out where the footer is aligning itself to. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: mmm...ok i will try to description it in another answer, but just wait my friend and don't worry

Comment: Thank you so much. They basically want me giving height, width attributes to everything and then placing the central images in a table. I just can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>Header</header>
<div id="main">
  <article>
    <div class="my-container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
      </div>
    </div>

  </article>
  <nav>Nav</nav>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
  #main > article {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  #main > nav, 
  #main > aside {
    flex: 0 0 20vw;
  }
  #main > nav {
    background: #D7E8D4;
    order: 3;
  }

  header, footer {
    background: yellowgreen;
    height: 20vh;
  }
  header, footer, article, nav, aside {
    padding: 1em;
  }

  .my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start; /* pack wrapping lines to the top */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {enter code here
  max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can use this code simple flex css concept if you need some more inputs you can use following URL as reference https://www.quackit.com/html/templates/css_flexbox_templates.cfm for now you can use above code directly for your purpose

Comment: Is there a way to do it without flex? The only things I've been taught so far are in relation to padding and margins. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** try to learn instead copy & paste it, to start try to write codes again.

*I change and also add some css class in your codes, so pay-attention to different between old version and new css and html files.*

**Description:** for start modeling your style you need to separate all partsyou need; for example here we need:

1. Header
2. Header > image
3. main > nav
4. main > content
5. main > content > header
6. main > content > subheading
7. main > content > area
8. main > content > area > items
9. main > content > area > items > item
10. etc...

and then start to html them, insert your div or what you want, and last step is manage them with css.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagebanner {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: brown;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
  background-color: #f8d631;
  margin: 0;
}

.area h3 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.item div {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.item img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class="pagebanner">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1400/1*278tqw9zNPe2WCAz29Wzdw.jpeg" alt="PageBanner">
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>The Club Site</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subheading">
          <h2>Members Prices</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="area">
          <h3>discounted Items</h3>

          <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div>
                <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7VG9DQVluOFJ4Tnc/materialdesign-principles-metaphor.png" />
                <h4>name - %200</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mate thank you for this. it helps so much. It'll take me abit to go through it all and understand it but it seems I was missing the divs for the items that go within the container divs. Is this correct? And to add the footer I would just need to add another div within the content container, is this also correct?

Comment: i didn't add footer because i want you to challenge your self to get more experience about `html` and `css`, but as i said before do not copy try to make them again, always before start design your model on the page and then do it.

Comment: Ahk gotcha. I definitely want and need to understand all of this. Just one more question. I tried adding a footer and it seemed to change the colour of the entire background. I should just be able to give it width and height attributes and it will contain itself? Plus I would like to do a bit of we design in the future and feel this is about as basic as it gets. Need to know the fundamentals.

Comment: did you try what you said right now?! codes aren't monster, try them (more than 1 time) and then ask

Comment: Will do, just wanted to try and get all possible questions out there while you were online to see them. If I run into any issues I may be back. Again, thanks heaps for taking the time to help me out.